# Share a variable between a component and a service in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I need to implement a loading/spinner image in Angular 6. The spinner should be displayed when an HTTP service sends a request, and hidden when the service receives a response.

I implemented the image in a component, note the `loading` variable:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-spinner',
  templateUrl: `
            <div class="center-all" *ngIf="loading">
                 <img src="spinner.gif"></img>
            </div> 
  `,
  styles: [ `
      .center-all {
          position: fixed; 
          top: 0; 
          left: 0;
          z-index: 99999;
          margin: -8px;
      }
  `],
})
export class MySpinnerComponent {}
```

My HTTP service should change the `loading` variable directly (without passing through the parent component that declares `MySpinnerComponent` and invokes the `MyHttpService`).

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyHttpService {

    loading = false;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    static handleError (error: Response) {
      console.error(error);
      return Observable.throw(error || 'Server error');
    }

    public call (params) {

       this.loading = true;  // how to share this variable with the spinner component?

        return this.http.post<any>(params.url, params.data).
          pipe(
              map(response => response),
              tap(this.loading = false),
              catchError(VbkHttpService.handleError)
          );
    }

}
```

In AngularJS, I declared the variable in `$rootScope` so I could share it. But how to implement the equivalent in Angular 6?

Comment: are you calling `MyHttpService ` from your  `MySpinnerComponent`

Comment: No, I'm calling MyHttpService from a parent component that declares MySpinnerComponent

Comment: then use `MySpinnerComponent ` selector in the template of the parent component with an ngIf

Comment: Your service is declared as a **Singleton**, why would you want to share a loading flag **application-wide** ? Your *loading flag* should be **unique for each request**. Why not declate a `isLoading` boolean inside your component ? When you call the service, you set your `isLoading` flag to true, and set it to false when you have an answer/error.

Comment: @Florian I don't want to code in each component the logic to handle the spinner. I can have a counter in the Singleton that increments with each request, and subtract with each response. When the counter is zero then the spinner will be hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add event emitter to service

```
loadingChange=new EventEmitter<boolean>();
```

everytime you change `loading` field, emit event with `this.loadingChange.emit(this.loading)`;

and in spinner component, subscribe to that event emitter.

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-spinner',
      templateUrl: `
                <div class="center-all" *ngIf="loading">
                     <img src="spinner.gif"></img>
                </div> 
      `,
      styles: [ `
          .center-all {
              position: fixed; 
              top: 0; 
              left: 0;
              z-index: 99999;
              margin: -8px;
          }
      `],
    })
    export class MySpinnerComponent{

    loading=false;

    constructor(private service:MyService){
        this.myService.loadingChange.subscribe(flag=>this.loading=flag);
    }
}
```

**OR**

You could also simply make `loading` field public and access it directly from the timeplate like this:

service:

```
public loading;
```

component

```
  @Component({
      selector: 'my-spinner',
      templateUrl: `
                <div class="center-all" *ngIf="service.loading">
                     <img src="spinner.gif"></img>
                </div> 
      `,
      styles: [ `
          .center-all {
              position: fixed; 
              top: 0; 
              left: 0;
              z-index: 99999;
              margin: -8px;
          }
      `],
    })
    export class MySpinnerComponent{
    constructor(private service:MyService){
    }
}
```

I just prefer "the emitter" way

Comment: EventEmitter shouldn't be subscribed manually, this is anti-pattern. The purpose of EventEmitter is to emit events in components.

Comment: EventEmitter is great and simple to use implementation of `Observable`. Is it anti-pattern to subscribe to observables? I guess not.

Comment: You should use a `Subject` or a derived one such as `BehaviorSubject` (if you want an intial value), or `ReplaySubject`, etc.

Comment: As a side not, a loading should not be located in a **Singleton service**, what if you have two components loading and one ends before the other ? Maybe you could update your answer and I could upvote it :)

Comment: @Florian that would be OPs problem i guess. He asked on how to share flag - he got the answer.

Comment: I ended up using the public field, is the simplest solution

Answer (score 1):

Spinner should be handled in Component, not service.

When you call a service from conponent:

```
  someFunction() {
    this.loading = true; // This will display a child spinner component
    this._service.call().subscribe({
      next: (result) => {
        // Do something with result here
      },
      error: (err) => { // handle error here
        this.loading = false;
      },
      complete: () => {
        this.loading = false;
      }
    });
  }
```

when the call is completed - 'Complete' will be called and hide spinner.

EDIT: Adding error handling as mentioned in comments.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This wont set loading to false spinner in case of error.

Comment: Updated - nothing was mentioned about error handling, but code above will handle error situation now :)

Comment: above code is repeating itself. You should just use `finalize` operator for that

Comment: Not sure what do you mean, works perfectly for me, sir :)

Comment: I mean,  that I dont like repeating myself in code like you do